# Using datapoint multiple times in error

Tags: regression, linear-model, error, measurement-error

For a simple regression problem, say I have a function $f = x^2 + ax$ and am using mean squared error as a loss function. In each calculation of mean squared error, each datapoint gets used twice (both $x$ terms in the function). Is this a potential problem with the final error metric – would the metric be an overestimate or underestimate of the actual error since it uses each datapoint twice?

My initial thoughts were that because each datapoint is used twice, the penalty for being further away from the actual value would be greater. When summing all the terms up, the overall MSE would be greater, therefore being an overestimate. However, I'm unsure about the veracity of these statements, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Could you please be more specific about how a "datapoint" gets "used twice"?  Many people would understand you to be fitting a dataset of the form $(x_i,y_i)$ by finding a value of $a$ that minimizes the sum of squared differences between the $y_i$ and $x_i^2 + a x_i.$  That's a straightforward univariate regression which involves each data point only *once.*

Answer (score 1):

The least squares error formula can be derived by assuming that once you have found your best estimator $\hat{y}=f(x)$, that the observed values of y will be normally distributed around this value, i.e. $y|x \sim N(f(x), \sigma)$

Provided different measurements of y are *i.i.d*, the least squares formula drops out when you maximise the likelihood of your data. Thus using least squares is fine, provided all of the usual assumptions of homoskedasticity apply.

I would argue that you're only using x once, when you insert it into $f(x)$.